# React createClass specification object formatting

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Probably an elementary question, but why is it in React, when you use `createClass` it can take an [specification object](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html) in a format that is a key-value pair, such as

```
React.createClass({
   render: function () {...},
   componentDidMount: function () {...}
})
```

vs. a function declaration?

```
React.createClass({
   render () {...},
   componentDidMount () {...}
})
```

How can they both work? Does react magically change the declarations into an object key value pair for you?

Comment: actually they are the same.. the other one just uses the new ES syntax. i think its ES2015.. check this [link](http://es6-features.org/#MethodProperties)

Answer (score 2):

They are the same. One is [Method Definitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Method_definitions) from ES2015 and the other is the traditional way. So, no React doesn't do anything but it's just how JavaScript works now. (As long as the browser supports it or a preprocessor like Babel converts it to ES5)